# Mousemove on div changes when mouseover elements

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to detect the position of the mouse in the holder div when it moves. However, when I move my mose over SVG elements within the holder div it will take the relative position to the this element and not the holder div. Anyone an idea how I can prevent this? Below see the code I used:

```
var R = Raphael("holder", canw, canh);

$('#holder').mousemove(function (event){
    if(mousemove){
      position = getPosition(event);
      console.log(position.x+" - "+position.y);
    }
  });

function getPosition(e) {
    //this section is from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html
    console.log(e);
    var targ;
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;
    if (e.target)
        targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement)
        targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    console.log(targ);
    // jQuery normalizes the pageX and pageY
    // pageX,Y are the mouse positions relative to the document
    // offset() returns the position of the element relative to the document
    var x = e.pageX - $(targ).offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY - $(targ).offset().top;
    return {"x": x, "y": y};
};

<div id="holder"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.currentTarget) instead of `event.target` - this will give you the element you attached the listener to rather than the element that received the event. So your position will be calculated relative to the `#holder` element.

Since you are using jQuery this should work in Internet Explorer as well (jQuery apparently  [emulates `event.currentTarget` there](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)). Other IE compatibility hacks (`window.event` and `event.srcElement`) shouldn't be required either.