# How to not change an event offset when the event occurs on its child element

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, offset, onmousemove

```
 window.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>
 {   
     console.log(e.offsetX + ' && ' + e.offsetY);
 });
```

When I move my cursor over the background, no issues are detected but when the cursor moves over another element, the offset value relative to the element is received. So, I just want to have the offset value w.r.t to the window.

Comment: your question is unclear , but check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714843/mousemove-on-div-changes-when-mouseover-elements)

Comment: @BrightFaith I have a text element at the center of my window. I added an event listener 'mousemove' to my background image and use the offsetX and offsetY function. But when my cursor moves to the text element, the value of offsetX and offsetY is received to be w.r.t to the text element not with the whole background window.
I mean when mouse enters text element (or div) the value of offsetX and offsetY is redeclared as 0.

Comment: then you should write an if condition inside your mousemove event Listener , assuming param `e` is passed inside , containing event object 
inside your if condition write `if (e.currentTarget == yourBackgroundElement)` , because your text is a child of your background , the Event is being executed for the text too , above condition says when this event is executing for the background element , do the code . it was better if you would provide full code including html but i think your problem is what i said

Comment: <div class = "image">
<div id="text">  
  <h3>Q.1. Which of the following movies follows 3 main interrelated storylines</h3>   
  <p id="option1">Pulp Fiction</p>
  <p id="option2">Scent of a woman</p>
</div>
</div>

Comment: document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{

    var X=Math.floor(e.offsetX/15);
   var Y=Math.floor(e.offsetY/7);
        
e.target.style.backgroundImage =  `linear-gradient(to right,rgba(${X}, 20, ${Y}, 0.5),rgba(${X}, 20, ${Y}, 0.5)),url("image.jpg")`;

});

Comment: @BrightFaith the above comments are my HTML code and the JS code